# set up another email server(@demo.local) within a large company(@example.com)

Tags: email, email-server

I want to set up an email server in a large company, and actually they already have their mail server, and I wonder if I want to set up another internal email server (specific for our solution, no need to connect to internet, just enable their server can forward email to my server at XXX@demo.local).
Is this possible ? Do I need another domain ? or just use domain demo.local will work ?
If the hmailServer doesn't connect with their active directory, then can their server recognize my server and can send email to XXX@demo.local?

Comment: This question is probably better asked on Serverfault. I've voted for it to be moved there and once enough others vote, it'll be moved automatically.

Comment: I recommend editing the question and giving the server unique names (like `primary.example.com` and `myone.example.com`, you company domain will be probably `example.com`). It will be much easier to understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

> If the hmailServer doesn't connect with their active directory, then can their server recognize my server and can send email to XXX@demo.local?

It is certainly possible.  SMTP MTAs (mail transfer agents) routes mail based on locally defined rules on the mail server, and DNS.  So the possibility of getting email delivered from your corporate mail server, to a different domain completely depends on how the corporate email server is setup to route email.

If the corporate server uses DNS even for internal mail routing, and you can make changes to the internal DNS, you simply need to get [MX records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) setup for your mail server and domain on the internal DNS servers.

If they don't use DNS for internal email routing, then you may need to talk the corporate mail server admins into setting up a SMTP route just for your domain.  How you do this is drastically different depending on what mail server that is in use.

Without knowing how your network is setup, there is no way to say with certainty if this is possible in your environment.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, and they are using exchange server as company email server, is it possible: I set up a server at [192.168.2.33], then ask their email server to forward all emails to helloworld@192.168.2.33?  if it's possible, then we don't need to cater the domain problem, am I right ?

Comment: @Hooligan: That is not possible since that would be a syntax error.

Comment: then how can I implement the solution above ? could you please describe it in more detail ? as I know, if I our email server can not join their AD, then how can I set up a XXX@demo.local email address ?